# API: Making constructor functions chainable without parenthesis in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, object, native, chaining

So I am building out some chainable functions that does simple type checking. Currently, I have to call my functions like this:

```
Proceed().if('someString').is.a('string');
```

But what I **really want** is for my API to look like this:

```
proceed.if('someString').is.a('string');
```

Notice that in the second code sample, the opening and closing parenthesis are missing from the first function call.

As you can see from the code below, I have already figured out how to get the `is` and `a` to work, but I can't seem to find a way to remove the parenthesis from the `Proceed()` function.

Here is the code sample **that works**:

```
function Proceed() {
  if (!(this instanceof Proceed)) {
      return new Proceed();
    }
    this.target = "";
}

Proceed.prototype.if = function (target) {
    this.target = target;
    return this;
}

Proceed.prototype.a = function (type) {
    console.log(this.target + ' === ' +type, typeof this.target === type);
};

Object.defineProperty(Proceed.prototype, 'is', {
        get: function () {
            return this;
        }
    });


Proceed().if('someString').is.a('string'); // true
Proceed().if('someString').is.a('function'); // false


// Everything Above this line Works!
```

And now, my attempt to remove the parenthesis from `Proceed()` looks like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Proceed.prototype, 'proceed', {
  set: function(){},
  get: function(){
    return Proceed(this);
  },
  configurable: true
});

proceed.if('someString').is.a('string');    // ReferenceError
proceed.if('someString').is.a('function');  // ReferenceError
```

The error I get from here is this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: proceed is not defined

If I swap out `Proceed.prototype` with `Object.prototype` then I can get it to work, but that means I have extended a native object, which can be problematic.

So does anyone know of a way I can pull this off without dangerously extending the native object? What am I doing wrong here?

**[Here is a jsFiddle with the above code samples](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/2/).**

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE #1** This code is being designed as a node module, so there won't be any access to the browser's `window` object.

Comment: Don't think you can without extending Object or window. I have tested with window instead of Proceed: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with a instance-valued variable:

```
var proceed = new Proceed();
```

And to make it chainable, you should return new instances from your methods instead of mutating the "static" `proceed` object:

```
function Proceed(target) {
    this.target = arguments.length ? target : "";
}

Proceed.prototype.if = function (target) {
    return new Proceed(target);
}
```

Or in general, you need to make `proceed.if` a factory that returns `Proceed` instances, regardless whether `proceed` already is one or just a normal object.

[(jsfiddle demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/7/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this! At first glance, it appears to work, but it also has the side effect of not returning new instances on each call. Each time I call `proceed.if()...` I need a new instance of `Proceed`, but in your demo, I found that each subsequent call was retaining values from the previous call, as if `proceed` was just a variable. I updated your demo with the demonstration. Notice the console.log() statements at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/6/. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Oops, [that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/5/) had two `if` methods, your old implementation overwriting the working one from my answer. Fixed.

Comment: Beautiful! That works for me. Thank you very much! You just helped me [close this ticket](https://github.com/radiovisual/detonate/issues/1) on my experimental library. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Object.defineProperty(Proceed.prototype, 'proceed', {
```

to

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'proceed', {
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw29zyf1/4/

So you will have a "proceed" variable in the window scope.

Comment: Yeah, this does help get the job done! However, I need this to also work in a self-contained node environment where I won't have access to the window object. I will update my question to let readers know that this code should be capable of running in node as well as the browser. Thanks!

Comment: But this is a good answer for those looking to do something similar in the browser environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the below code is of any help

```
var proto = Object.create(null);
proto.a = function(type) {
 console.log(this.target + ' === ' + type, typeof this.target === type);

};

Object.defineProperty(proto, 'is', {
    get: function() {
       return this;
    }
});

proto.if = function(target) {
 this.target = target;
 return this;

};


var proceed = Object.create(proto);

proceed.if('someString').is.a('string');
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used `Object.create`, please?

Comment: Because its the only way we can assign a prototype to an object without using constructor functions.

Comment: This works in the sense that it *does* create the desired API, but your example is creating an object, instead of using functions, and the question was centered on functions. However, this does get the job done if I were using objects, so I appreciate your input!